# C++ program does nothing but Valgrind shows memory alloc

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-leaks, valgrind

I was toying around with Valgrind, when I noticed something weird: 
my C++ program does nothing, yet there is 1 memory alloc and 1 free.

My simple program:

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

when compiled with g++ and checked with Valgrind

```
> g++ main.cpp
> valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./a.out

==40790== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==40790== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==40790== Using Valgrind-3.16.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==40790== Command: ./a.out
==40790== 
==40790== 
==40790== HEAP SUMMARY:
==40790==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40790==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==40790== 
==40790== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==40790== 
==40790== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==40790== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**My question: My program does nothing. Where does the alloc and free come from?**

Interestingly enough, the same program compiled with gcc, shows zero allocs and frees:

```
> gcc main.c
> valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./a.out
==40740== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==40740== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==40740== Using Valgrind-3.16.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==40740== Command: ./a.out
==40740== 
==40740== 
==40740== HEAP SUMMARY:
==40740==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40740==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==40740== 
==40740== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==40740== 
==40740== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==40740== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Follow up question: Why do the two memory allocations differ, for the same piece of code?**

compiler: gcc (GCC) 10.1.0
valgrind: valgrind-3.16.0.GIT

Comment: The C++ library allocated something for its own use, and deleted it. Nothing exciting happened here.

Comment: what would that be, if I didn't link or #include anything?

Comment: You most certainly linked to something: the standard C++ library. Your compiler did it for you.

Comment: @Donald there are many things that happen before main, you can use a tool like a `gdb` to have a look and see what's going on if you're curious :)

Answer (score 1):

[The main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) is the entry point of your code. It doesn't have to be (and seldom is) the entry point to the process for the operating system that is loading your program.

There's usually plenty of code running first to set up things needed for the standard library (like setting up the standard I/O streams, and fetching the actual arguments from the operating system) before your main function is called.

And it's important to note that the `main` function is called like any other function. Once it returns it will return to the initialization code which will now clean up after itself (like freeing memory it might have allocated, and closing streams, etc.).

Comment: First sentence of the last para is a bit clumsy - `main()` is not called like any other function.   It is only called from the "plenty of code" that sets things up for the program, and the C++ standard explicitly disallows calling it from any other code.    Yes, some implementations may call it like any other function (i.e. with those particular implementations, `main()` is called like any other function) but the C++ standard doesn't require that.